# Do we need to add xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to every root view of an XML file?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

If I have made a `LinearLayout`, added `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and closed it, will I need to add the namespace again to another `ViewGroup` in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the namespace needs to be declared on every *root* view if you want to use `andorid:` prefixed attributes. However no, you don't need to declare the namespace on a different `ViewGroup` in the same file (and having multiple roots is not permitted).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout />
</FrameLayout>
```

You can take a look at [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) from W3Schools which describes what namespaces are and why they're important.

Comment: `<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 [other views]>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
 [other views]>
</LinearLayout>`

Is this code okay or I need to do this?:

`<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 [other views]>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 [other views]>
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: Well you can't have multiple roots in your layout file, it doesn't make any sense. So neither of those examples really work.

Comment: Can you please provide an example in which this namespace is used? Please include 2 or more view groups.

Comment: Added a sample to my answer.